# Extract a specific number from a string

Tags: python, string

I have this string `553943040  21%   50.83MB/s    0:00:39`

- The length of the numbers can vary
- The percent can contain one or two numbers
- The spaces between the start of the string and the first number may vary

I need to extract the first number, in this case `553943040`

I was thinking that the method could be to:

1) Replace the percent with a separator. something like:

```
string=string.replace("..%","|") # where the "." represent any character, even an space.
```

2) Get the first part of the new string by cutting everything after the separator.

```
string=string.split("|")
string=string[0]
```

3) Remove the spaces.

```
string=string.strip()
```

I know that the stages 2 and 3 works, but I'm stocked on the first. Also if there is any better method of getting it would be great to know it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much work.

```
>>> '553943040 21% 50.83MB/s 0:00:39'.split()[0]
'553943040'
```

Comment: well, this is by far much more simpler than i thought. Thanks, I'll accept the answer when i can